# Split up numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I've been looking all over but I'm not really sure how to even describe what it is I want. Essentially I need to turn

```
np.array(
    [[0,0, 1,1, 2,2],
     [0,0, 1,1, 2,2],
     [3,3, 4,4, 5,5],
     [3,3, 4,4, 5,5]]
)
```

into

```
np.array(
    [[[0,1,2,3,4,5], [0,1,2,3,4,5]],
     [[0,1,2,3,4,5], [0,1,2,3,4,5]]
)
```

I think I can accomplish that using `np.reshape` and maybe some other stuff but if I try `reshape` with arguments `(2,2,6)` I get back

```
[[[0 0 1 1 2 2]
  [0 0 1 1 2 2]]

 [[3 3 4 4 5 5]
  [3 3 4 4 5 5]]]
```

which is not quite what I want.

Comment: are the new values in resulting arrays just indicies of the original array?

Comment: @AnnaSlastnikova no they are those values that were in the original matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your array with a couple of repeats:

```
In [208]: arr = np.arange(0,6).reshape(2,3)
In [209]: arr
Out[209]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
In [210]: arr = arr.repeat(2,0).repeat(2,1)
In [211]: arr
Out[211]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
       [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]])
```

Now break it into blocks which we can transpose:

```
In [215]: arr1 = arr.reshape(2,2,3,2)
In [216]: arr1
Out[216]: 
array([[[[0, 0],
         [1, 1],
         [2, 2]],

        [[0, 0],
         [1, 1],
         [2, 2]]],


       [[[3, 3],
         [4, 4],
         [5, 5]],

        [[3, 3],
         [4, 4],
         [5, 5]]]])
In [217]: arr1.shape
Out[217]: (2, 2, 3, 2)
In [218]: arr1.transpose(1,0,2,3)
Out[218]: 
array([[[[0, 0],
         [1, 1],
         [2, 2]],

        [[3, 3],
         [4, 4],
         [5, 5]]],


       [[[0, 0],
         [1, 1],
         [2, 2]],

        [[3, 3],
         [4, 4],
         [5, 5]]]])
```

Let's consolidate the middle 2 axes:

```
In [220]: arr1.transpose(1,0,2,3).reshape(2,6,2)
Out[220]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [4, 4],
        [5, 5]],

       [[0, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [4, 4],
        [5, 5]]])
```

Almost there; just need another transpose:

```
In [221]: arr1.transpose(1,0,2,3).reshape(2,6,2).transpose(0,2,1)
Out[221]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]])
```

The basic idea is to reshape the array into blocks, do a transpose, and reshape again.  Here I needed another transpose, but if I choose the right one to start with I might not have needed that.

I don't know of a systematic way of doing this; there may be one, but so far I've just used a bit of trial and error when answering this kind of question.  Everyone wants a different final arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array(
...     [[0,0, 1,1, 2,2],
...      [0,0, 1,1, 2,2],
...      [3,3, 4,4, 5,5],
...      [3,3, 4,4, 5,5]]
... )
```

```py
>>> B = a[::2,::2].flatten()
>>> B
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

```py
>>> C = np.tile(b, (2,2,1))
>>> C
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]])
```

We can generalize this for a given `n * m` matrix, that contain blocks sized `n/y * m/x` of identical values (so there are `y` rows and `x` columns of blocks)

```py
def transform(A, y, x):
    dy = A.shape[0]/y
    dx = A.shape[1]/x
    B = A[::dy, ::dx].flatten()
    return np.tile(B, (y,x,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import numpy
b=numpy.array([[0,0,1,1,2,2],[0,0,1,1,2,2],[3,3,4,4,5,5],[3,3,4,4,5,5]])
c1=(b[::2,::2].flatten(),b[::2,1::2].flatten())
c2=(b[1::2,::2].flatten(),b[1::2,1::2].flatten())
c=numpy.vstack((c1,c2)).reshape((2,2,6))
print(c)
```

which outputs:

```
[[[0 1 2 3 4 5]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4 5]
  [0 1 2 3 4 5]]]
```

and for general size target array and general size input array this is the algorithm with an example of 3*3 input array:

```
import numpy
b=numpy.array([[0,0,1,1,2,2],[0,0,1,1,2,2],[0,0,1,1,2,2],[3,3,4,4,5,5],[3,3,4,4,5,5],[3,3,4,4,5,5]])
(m,n)=b.shape
C=b[::int(m/2),::2].flatten(),b[::int(m/2),1::2].flatten()
for i in range(1,int(m/2)):
    C=numpy.vstack((C,(b[i::int(m/2),::2].flatten(),b[i::int(m/2),1::2].flatten())))
print(C)
```

which outputs:

```
[[0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5]]
```

Comment: Close, I just need it generalized now. Like for an `m * n` matrix where the final array will be of size `r * c * d`

Comment: I don't understand how this is different, the algorithm remains the same: you do the same 4 iterations over the array no matter of what size it is, and no matter of what size you want...
Edited the answer.

Comment: What if you want a `3 * 3`? Then we would need 3 `c` arrays and the slice would be of the form `[::3]`. I'm trying to avoid `for ` loops and just use whatever `numpy` has naturally

Comment: @theEpsilon I re-edited my answer, assuming this is the input pattern you were talking about.